# Get every n-th element of list starting from maximum value

Tags: python, list

I have an array of numbers:

```py
y = np.random.rand(1000)
```

What I want to do is to find the maximum value of `y` and then take every n-th element starting from that value's position, both before and after that maximum value occurrence.

I can not seem to be able to go backwards in the array.

I can easily find the maximum and take every n-th element from there:

```py
idx = np.argmax(y)
newy = y[idx::reprate] # reprate is the number of points I want to skip
```

This, however, excludes all the n-th points before `idx`, which I still want to get.

Is there a straightforward way I am not seeing?

Comment: From a glance, I think you just need to change the slice to `[idx::-reprate]`

Comment: Is it sorted or random?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse If it were sorted, wouldn't the maximum be at the end/start?

Comment: @wjandrea Not if it was rotated (i.e. if it was sorted then rotated). Though I didn't word that properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finding the first index of your array that you want to keep is simple math: `idx % reprate`

```
newy = y[idx%reprate::reprate]
```

Comment: I cannot believe I did not think of this. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option without NumPy:

```
import random
# Generating the random list
y = random.sample(range(1, 1000), 1000)
n = 3

# This will get the index of the max element
index = max(enumerate(y), key=lambda x: x[1])[0]

# This will get every `n` element
every_n_element = [y[(i + index) % len(y)] for i in range(0, len(y), n)]
print(every_n_element)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add a negative to your stride and that will go backwards.

Simple example here. This will start at the index you provide, and then stride by 2 both forwards through the iterable and then backwards through the iterable.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> a[4::2]
[5, 7, 9]
>>> a[4::-2]
[5, 3, 1]
```

Comment: Hi, yes, I am aware of that; I can do it for both directions and then concatenate the two arrays. This, however, will give me twice the initial value

Comment: @Enzo Then just subtract `reprate` once from `idx`: `a[4-2::-2] == [3, 1]`